# Display base64 data in Iframe Not working in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, csp

We have a requirement to show google drive contents(pdf,txt,docs,xlsx,images) in a modal in lightning experience.

Below is what I did so far:

1) Get the `base64` content of the drive file using Apex Callout.

2) Set the iframe tag's `url` attribute to the base64 content inside the Lightning Component.

When I view the modal in LEX, I get the below error:

> Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-src https: mailto:

But if I view the same lightning component inside a VFpage in Classic view using lightning-out, the modal shows the contents properly.

I tried adding the drive url : `https://www.googleapis.com` in CSP and CORS setting but nothing works.

Lightning View

[image]

Classic View

[image]

Issue

[image]

Comment: is the vf page thing not working in lightning ?

Comment: Vf pages are not supported by Lightning,So we have used to the lightning component

Comment: Hi @Gowthamsakthi - were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @vilelam No,We just downloaded the content

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar issue a couple days ago and was able to resolve it by adding `data:` to the CSP trusted sites.